Logarithm properties
I teach an online college math course and for one assignment, some students used a logarithm simplification technique that appears on A1. However, it is not on traditional log property lists. Is this a valid technique and if so, can you suggest a link to a good math website where I can see it listed? Thank you! (I am new to asking questions on here - I was not sure how to type a subscript - sorry!)
Here is an example:
$$2\operatorname{log}_9(x+1)-\operatorname{log}_9(y)$$
After they simplified to $$\operatorname{log}_9\bigg(\frac{(x+1)^2}{y}\bigg)$$ they then went to
$$\operatorname{log}_{3^2}\bigg(\frac{(x+1)^2}{y}\bigg)$$ and then $$\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{log}_3\bigg(\frac{(x+1)^2}{y}\bigg).$$
Is it valid to make your base an exponential expression?

This is difficult to read. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Enclosing math expressions in "$" goes a long way towards proper formatting

Without addressing your question directly (as I can't read it), you can always program the proposed relation and test it numerically.  Of course, if it is true, you'll want a proof, not just some examples, but if it fails numerically then it is false.
